# Table row that highlights on hover and changes color on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jquery to handle both cases. Basically the functionality I want is for the table rows to highlight when you hover over them, but when you click on one for that specific row to turn a darker color than the hover's highlight. This is the code I currently have

```
$("tr").not(':first').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css("background", "#FFEFC6");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css("background", "");
  }
);

$("tr").click(function(e) {
  $(this).css("background-color", "#ffd659");
});
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I click on a row, it will turn the darker color, but if I hover away from this row, it will revert back to a transparent background.

Comment: provide html code or fiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CSS, there is no need to use JavaScript for the hover
So just toggle the class on click

```js
$("tbody").on("click", "tr", function(e) {     
  $(this)
     .toggleClass("selected")
     .siblings(".selected")
         .removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
table { width: 50% }
tbody tr:hover.selected td,
tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: #FFEFC6;
  cursor: pointer;
}
tbody tr.selected td {
  background-color: #ffd659;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: for extra WOW, use the CSS transition property

Comment: This does not work. When I click a row nothing happens.

Comment: Because there was a typo...It was missing `"` around the tr

Comment: Thanks! Working now. I know I didn't ask in the original posting, but is it possible to make it so that only one row can be "clicked" at any time?

Comment: Yes, just remove the selected class from its siblings. See edit.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.

Comment: @epascarello I have been searching for a solution pretty similar to this. However, I was trying to put this to work on a particular table ID. So I did something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/akshaysuri/twya05x1/ but the color does not change on selection. Can you help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr").not(':first').hover(
   function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass("sel"))
              $(this).css("background", "#FFEFC6");
  },
  function() {
     if(!$(this).hasClass("sel"))
        $(this).css("background", "");
  }
);

$("tr").click(function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#ffd659");
    $(this).addClass("sel");
});
```

AND your css can be.

```
td
{
    width:40px;

}

sel
{
background-color:#ffd659

}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/szup0x8k/9/